# How to add a URL to "Available Software Site" preference programmatically

Tags: eclipse, p2

I need to utilize the P2 update feature in Eclipse to update my product.
The "Updates" tab in the product file editor of Eclipse seems broken.
The tab says the URL entries added in this tab should appear in "Available Software Site".
I added a URL in the Updates tab, but it is not shown in the Available Software Site preference page of the product.

I already tried the instruction in https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html#adding-p2-update-sites, and created a p2.inf file that includes the appropriate URL.
Still, I found no URL in the preference.
I tried to import a sample project in https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.sdkui, but this sample still showed the same issue.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: For example, if you have a product file `myProduct.product`, the p2 inf file must be named `myProduct.p2.inf` and located in the same folder (see e.g. [here which works for me](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/tree/master/product)). If this does not help, show your product and p2 inf files, your project structure and tell how you build the product (manually via Eclipse, via Tycho, etc.) and which Eclipse version do you use as target platform.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, howlger. I tried to rename the p2.inf file with the product name, but it did not help. You can see the example project in https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.sdkui.

Comment: I cloned this example, and imported the sdkui project into Eclipse 2019-03 committers version. when I built and ran it, I don't see any URL in Available Software Site.

Comment: The `p2.inf` in that example does make sense to me. As far as I know an update site can be added by a feature or a product, but not by a plug-in that way. The example is a plug-in that contains in addition a product definition. What do you build? The plug-in only (in this case the `.product` file is ignored) or the [product containing that plug-in](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.sdkui/sdkui.product#n73) and other plug-ins?

Comment: I just imported the plugin org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.sdkui, and changed the JRE System Library to Java 11 and build it in Eclipse 2019-03. The run configuration in Eclipse is "Run a product" which points to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.sdkui.product. And I set the Execution environment to Java 11. I had to select all Target Platform plguins in the "Plug-ins" tab of the run configuration to run the product. Otherwise, it failed to run with errors. The app has a preference menu, and it does not show anything in Available Software Site section.

Comment: This example is created by Eclipse.org, and I am not sure why it does not work as described in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application.

Comment: So you didn't build the product, but launch it from inside Eclipse? Please show what you have and describe what you did. Please note that you refer to files that are older than ten years and therefore minor adjustments might be necessary.

Comment: Is there any way I can send the modified plugin to you? or attach in this website?

Comment: I only changed just a few settings as I described 3 comments above. I also tried the sample hello-world project in Eclipse 2019-03, I added p2.inf and added a URL in the project editor, and it still did not show any URL in preference.